# Why $\mu: \mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ rather than $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^N$?

Tags: functions, vectors, normal-distribution, means, fisher-information

> Multivariate normal distribution The FIM for a $N$-variate
> multivariate normal distribution, $X \sim N(\mu(\theta),
>  \Sigma(\theta))$ has a special form. Let the $K$-dimensional vector of
> parameters be $\theta=\left[\begin{array}{lll}\theta_{1} & \ldots &
>  \theta_{K}\end{array}\right]^{\top}$ and the vector of random normal
> variables be $X=\left[\begin{array}{lll}X_{1} & \ldots &
>  X_{N}\end{array}\right]^{\top} .$ Assume that the mean values of these
> random variables are $\mu(\theta)=\left[\mu_{1}(\theta) \quad \ldots
>  \quad \mu_{N}(\theta)\right]^{\top}$, and let $\Sigma(\theta)$ be the
> covariance matrix. Then, for $1 \leq m, n \leq K$, the $(m, n)$ entry
> of the FIM is: $^{[16]}$ $$ \mathcal{I}_{m, n}=\frac{\partial
>  \mu^{\top}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial
>  \mu}{\partial \theta_{n}}+\frac{1}{2}
>  \operatorname{tr}\left(\Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial
> \theta_{m}} \Sigma^{-1} \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial
>  \theta_{n}}\right) $$ where $(\cdot)^{\top}$ denotes the transpose of
> a vector, $\operatorname{tr}(\cdot)$ denotes the trace of a square
> matrix, and: $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial
>  \theta_{m}} &=\left[\begin{array}{lll} \frac{\partial
>  \mu_{1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \frac{\partial \mu_{2}}{\partial
>  \theta_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial \mu_{N}}{\partial \theta_{m}}
>  \end{array}\right]^{\top} \\ \frac{\partial \Sigma}{\partial
>  \theta_{m}} &=\left[\begin{array}{cccc} \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{1,1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{1,2}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{1, N}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \\ \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{2,1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{2,2}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \cdots & \frac{\partial
>  \Sigma_{2, N}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &
>  \vdots \\ \frac{\partial \Sigma_{N, 1}}{\partial \theta_{m}} &
>  \frac{\partial \Sigma_{N, 2}}{\partial \theta_{m}} & \cdots &
>  \frac{\partial \Sigma_{N, N}}{\partial \theta_{m}} \end{array}\right]
>  \end{aligned} $$

---

$$\mu(\theta)=\left[\mu_{1}(\theta) \quad \ldots
 \quad \mu_{N}(\theta)\right]^{\top} \implies \mu: \mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N.$$

I think it is false that $\mu: \mathbb{R}^K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N.$

So, $$\nexists \left[\mu_{1}(\theta) \quad \ldots
 \quad \mu_{N}(\theta)\right]^{\top} $$

The $\mu$ is not supposed to be a function but rather a vector independent of $\Sigma$ $$ \implies \mu \in \mathbb{R}^N \implies \mu \neq \left[\mu_{1}(\theta) \quad \ldots
 \quad \mu_{N}(\theta)\right]^{\top}  \implies \mu = \left[\mu_{1}\quad \ldots
 \quad \mu_{N}\right]^{\top}.  $$

---

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information

Comment: For a fixed $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^K$, the quantity $\mu(\theta)$ is a vector of size $N$. The function $\mu(\cdot)$ is $\mathbb{R}^K \to \mathbb{R}^N$ because it sends a vector $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^K$ to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: You estimate $\theta$. In a multivariate normal, you estimate the vector of means and the variance-covariance matrix. You're saying that $\theta \neq \mu, \Sigma_{ij}$ but this is a contradiction as $\mu, \Sigma_{ij} $ is estimated.

Comment: You did not explain why the other possibility was false.

Comment: The family of distributions is parameterized by $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^K$. The function $\mu$ maps $\theta$ to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^N$, while the function $\Sigma$ maps $\theta$ to a $N \times N$ matrix. For example, if $K=1$ you might have $\mu(\theta) := [\theta \; \theta \; \cdots \; \theta]^\top$ and $\Sigma(\theta) := |\theta| I$, and you can plug in different values of $\theta$ to obtain different normal distributions.

Comment: Under the case K=N, $\mu_1(\theta)=\theta, \mu_2(\theta)=\theta=...\mu_N(\theta)=\theta$. In reality, $\mu_1$ could be an arbitrary function of theta, $\mu_2(\theta) \neq \mu_1(\theta)$ and is arbitrary function, correct? Do you mean the exponential family of distributions is parametrized by $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^K$? You did not specify the K=1 case because K is the length of the n-tuple, and $[\theta \ \theta ... \ \theta_K]$ is a K-tuple

Comment: Actually, I realized you did specify K=1 case.

Comment: Yes, in general the functions $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots$ are arbitrary (but fixed, throughout the computation of the Fisher Information). Yes, the family of distributions being considered is parameterized by $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^K$ (although I don't know if it is an exponential family).